# Is is possible to get a single regex to replace 'str1/str2' with 'str1/str2,str1->str2'

Tags: regex, aptana

**The Problem**

I have a load of strings in this form:-

```
str1/str2
str3/str4/str5
```

There can be any number of segments. I would like to do a regex search and replace to get the output:-

```
str1/str2 , str1->str2
str3/str4/str5 , str3->str4->str5
```

My strings are actually in the form `[a-z|_]+`

**My attempt**

Match with:-

```
((?:(?:[a-z|_])\/?)+)
```

Replace with:-

```
$1 , $1
```

This is nearly right, but I'd need to do a second search and replace to change the `/`'s to `->`'s.

Can I achieve this with a single regex? Or does it depend on the engine I'm using and it's backreference capabilities? (I'm using the search and replace functionality in aptana).

Comment: Is there anything wrong with doing a second pass to make the second substitution? Sometimes the simplest solution is best. Why do you require this all be in one regular expression?

Comment: I guess I don't really need it to be in a single pass, I was just curious to know if there was a way - expand my knowledge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a repeating group does Aptana support a global modifier? This works in JavaScript:

```
"str3/str4/str5/str6/str7".replace(/([a-z0-9_|]+)\//g, '$1->');
//output: str_3->str_4->str_5->str_6->str_7
```

Also, I guess you meant your pattern should also allow numbers.